# Access to private keys of keychain on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, x509certificate, keychain

I'm implementing an application for Windows/Mac OS X on C# that digitally signs files with a certificate. To do that I'm using BouncyCastle and iText libraries. On windows works perfectly without any special code. I can read the stored certificates on the machine using this code.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates)
{
    if (certificate.HasPrivateKey && certificate.NotAfter >= DateTime.Now)
    {
        // USE CERTIFICATE
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is the access to the certificates stored in the Keychain. Because I can get the information of the certificates, but not their private keys. I suppose that there should be a way to access that information (after a confirmation from the user to allow the access), but I can't see how.
My current implementation to get the information of the certificates is:

```
var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.Certificate)
{
    MatchValidOnDate = DatetimeToNSDate(DateTime.Now),
    CanSign = true,
};

var certList = Security.SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(query, 100, out var result);
foreach(var cert in certLis)
{
    SecCertificate tempCertificate = new SecCertificate(cert);
    X509Certificate2 certificateObj = tempCertificate.ToX509Certificate2();
}
```

This `certificateObj` is a valid X509 certificate but its privateKey is null.

Comment: An X.509 certificate does not contain the private key, only the public key. If you want to store both the certificate, private- and public key, you should store it and retrieve it using the PKCS#12 standard

Comment: I have tried a workaround to export the certificate and the private key from the keychain into a P12 file, but from the command line it seems that it's not possible to export only a certificate and its private key, you can only export all the keychain, and nobody wants that.

Comment: KeyChain is a bit meticulous for exporting. You should be able to export your certificate into a .cer file and your key into a .p12 file. Then use openssl to convert where needed is what I'd recommend. But running all of this from code, you should be able to retrieve a private key by querying the keychain (as long as the key is created by the application) as well as the certificate. But it'll have to be two separate queries

Comment: Hi Bram, I have tried to export both on a P12 File and the X509Certificate works great and even it signs the files correctly. I would like to do this process from a command line tool to minimize the user interaction. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: I unfortunately have no experience with command line access to the KeyChain. I believe there is some `security` call you can do. You might want to check that out